Prononciation exacte de « est »
Selon cette base de données de phonetique française et d'autres sources aussi, le mot « est » (du verbe « être ») se prononce, utilisant l'Alphabet Phonetique International, comme [ɛ], c'est a dire, comme <e> ouverte.
Mais certaines fois j'entends aussi une prononciation avec une <e> férmée, c'est a dire [e].
Par example, utilisant le traducteur Google j'entends la phrase « Elle est partie » comme [ɛl ɛ paʁti], mais j'entends la phrase « Il est parti » comme [il e paʁti].
Est-ce vrai, ou suis-je délirant ? C'est a dire, est-ce vrai que ce mot se prononce parfois avec une e ouverte et parfois avec une e férmée ? Et en cas affirmatif, quelle est la règle ?

Tu n'es pas délirant, tu entends bien. Ça dépend de l'accent !

D'accord. Puis-je utiliser les deux alors ? Est-ce que l'une des deux sera mieux comprise par les autres francophones ?

Absolument. Même si certains sont surpris parce que ce n'est pas leur prononciation, tout le monde comprend, c'est le contexte qui donne le sens !
